# execute action on hotkey without capture it

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I want to execute action in my C# application when user clicks e.g. Ctrl+C combination.
I've found a spcific code, but i want - when user hits ctrl+c - the selected text will be copied & will be executed action in my app instead just execute action.

Answer (score 1):

Use a KeyDown event:

```
private void m_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) 
   {
      //Grab selected text
      Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
      string s = Clipboard.GetText();
      //Execute some action with the string
   }
}
```

You will also need to register the key event handler from the designer.cs for whetever you like to use it. Example:

```
this.richTextBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.m_KeyDown);
```

Comment: When you minimize your app, it looses focus and Ctrl+C for other applications simply means copy to clipboard. If you want your function to work independently of whether your application is in focus or nor, I am afraid I wouln't know how to do that. I would suggest you close this question and ask a new one where you are a bit more specific.